# In minecraftskins.com my skin wont change

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

[image]

I am keep trying and trying to change my skin and i dont
 want to buy mine craft again. Mine craft works fine but [the skindex](http://www.minecraftskins.com/) just wont let me get a new skin.This is the first time it did this.I am on pc ASUS

Answer (score 1):

**If you are on PC edition:** You are using the wrong account to login to minecraft.net

**If you are on Mobile Edition / Windows 10 Edition:** Open the skindex page on your phone. Pick a skin. Click Download button, not upload to minecraft on skindex. When you download it, go into app and apply it:

- Click the hanger icon.

[image: Hanger icon]

- Click the gray skin.

[image: Gray Skin]

- Click Choose New Skin button.

[image: Choose New Skin button]

- Pick the file you just downloaded, pick the correct skin type.

[image: Correct Skin Type popup]

- Click Confirm Skin. Your skin should be applied.

[image: Confirm Skin button]

Answer (score 0):

minecraftskins.com is only for the PC/Mac versions of Minecraft. MCPE uses an in-game skin system that I am somewhat unfamiliar with, but, in essence, you can choose from one of many preset skins, or create and use your own.

**Editors Note:**
The minecraft.net website has templates for both "steve" and "alex" skins to aid you in all your skin-creation related quests. Unfortunately, I am unable to log in to get the precise link at this time, and I apologize for that.

Comment: Wrong. You can use your own skin in PE.

Comment: Not wrong, just not complete.